# Remove additional brackets from an RDD using PySpark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am doing aggregation on a set of fields using Spark in Python. I am taking few values as input & creating an array out of it. Suppose i have 10 fields & i am creating an array with 2 elements like first 9 fields as Key & the 10 field as value & passing this to the reduceByKey method to do the aggregation.

The output i am getting has the array brackets, i am trying to eliminate those brackets before saving as a Textfile in HDFS.

Here is the output i am getting

```
('11', '2015', '919810051877', '102', 'MOC', 'LOCAL', 'A2LL', 'H', '40336', '237', '1', '', '01', '102', '27/01/2016 01:05:36', 'hramcha'),48,0.8
```

I wanted it as,

```
'11', '2015', '919810051877', '102', 'MOC', 'LOCAL', 'A2LL', 'H', '40336', '237', '1', '', '01', '102', '27/01/2016 01:05:36', 'hramcha',48,0.8
```

Here's the code. I have tried lot of things but unable to eliminate the brackets.

```
    #! /usr/bin/env python

import re
import sys
import time
import decimal

from pyspark import SparkContext
from decimal import Decimal

# function to extract the fields required for aggregation from the CDR files, based on position 
def extractData(line):
    bal = line.strip()
    (MSISDN,calling_no,called_no,other_party_no,start_date,start_time,end_date,end_time,duration,call_direction,call_type,call_leg,usage_type,roam_type,
    IMSI,IMEI,technology,message_type,dialled_digits,first_LAC,first_cell_id,last_LAC,last_cell_id,Tt_file_no,Tt_date_time,SMSC_ID,GSM_CRN,IC_route,OG_route,
    carrier_code,location_routing_no,other_party_operator_id,MSC_id,MSC_circle,HOME_circle,pre_post_flag,disconnecting_party,disconnection_reason,
    internal_cause_LOC,MSRN,original_calling_no,original_called_no,A_party_country_code,ICR_operator,calling_no_port,called_no_port,translated_no,global_ref_no,
    GSM_SCF_control_of_AoC,SMS_result_code,level_of_camel_service,message_ref_no,network_ref_no,ori_method,type_of_called_subscriber,call_fwd_no,
    partial_indicator,CLI,call_identification_no,Irn_odbi_ind) = bal.split("|")

    time_s = []
    time_s = start_time.split(":")
    hr = time_s[0]

    load_date = time.strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")
    load_user = "hramcha"

    return (start_date,hr,MSC_circle,HOME_circle,call_direction,call_type,call_leg,roam_type,first_cell_id,first_LAC,
    disconnection_reason,internal_cause_LOC,technology,pre_post_flag,load_date,load_user,duration)

# function to remove brackets from RDD before saving as textfile
def toCSVLine(data):
    return ','.join(str(d) for d in data)

# function to create an array of (all the fields, call_duration)
def formArray1(z):
    seg1 = z[0],z[1],z[2],z[3],z[4],z[5],z[6],z[7],z[8],z[9],z[10],z[11],z[12],z[13],z[14],z[15]
    seg2 = z[16]
    return seg1, seg2

# function to create an array and also calculate mins_of_usage
def calculateMins_of_usage(v):
    return v[0],v[1],float(v[1])/60


# create Spark Context with the master details and the application name
sc = SparkContext("spark://192.168.200.128:7077", "network_usage_HLY")

# create an RDD from the input data in HDFS
file = sc.textFile("hdfs://quickstart.cloudera/user/cloudera/input/network/",use_unicode=False) 

# group by all the fields & aggregate (sum) the call_duration
data_aggregated = file.map(extractData).map(formArray1).reduceByKey(lambda a ,b: (int(a) + int(b)))

# join the aggregation & calculate mins_of_usage
min_of_usage = data_aggregated.map(calculateMins_of_usage)

# calling toCSVLine function to remove brackets & braces
lines = min_of_usage.map(toCSVLine)

# save the final aggregated file in HDFS 
lines.saveAsTextFile("hdfs://quickstart.cloudera/user/cloudera/output/network")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm what you can do is to convert this array first to a string and then use regex to replace the brackets like this:

```
lines = min_of_usage.map(toCSVLine).map(lambda x: re.sub('\(|\)', '', str(x))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot... It helped. I was trying something with flatMap, but still was not satisfied with my result. But your code has helped. Thanks again. I was struggling with this from past 2 days.

Comment: I had one more doubt with the same program, I am dividing the aggregated sum with 60, which i am expecting a float result & i am getting the result like 1.6222223342 but i want it to round it to just with 2 decimals i.e 1.62. Can you suggest me something for this.

Comment: uhmm use round(float(v[1])/60, 2). That should give you the desired output

Comment: It gave the desired output. Thanks again :)